# Different update / edit methods available to different users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `Post`, which is submitted and graded by different `User`s. The submitter and grader are identified by `submitter_id` and `grader_id` in `Post` model. Note that an user is both a submitter himself and a grader to others.

I want to make sure that the submitter can only edit the content of the `Post` but not the grade. Likewise, the grader can only edit the grade but not the content.

Is multiple edit methods the way to go? How should I accomplish this otherwise?

Comment: Please add a tag indicating the version of Rails you are using.

Comment: Multiple edit methods are a way I have handled similar situations in the past... it does provide a pretty good way of separating the responsibilities... but it can be difficult to keep it dry... be sure to use partials for duplicate content when possible... separating it out like that also makes it fairly nice in the controller as you can manage access fairly easily... this approach does raise some concerns about injecting grader values into the parameters though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a role column in your `users` table, and the role can be either `submitter` or `grader`. Not sure what you are using for authentication, but in case you are using devise, you can access the currently logged in user with `current_user` helper (in case you are using something else, figure this part out, or add a new helper).

Now in your update method, you can do something like this:

```
# Controller
# scope post to current user, so that a user cannot edit someone else's post. A crude way to achieve this is post = Post.find(params[:id])
post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
post.content = params[:content] if post.submitter?(current_user.id)
post.grade = params[:grade] if post.grader?(current_user.id)
post.save!

# Model - Post.rb
def submitter?(user_id)
  self.submitter_id == user_id
end

def grader?(user_id)
  self.grader_id == user_id
end
```

The advantage of keeping those methods in the model is that in case you permission logic changes (who is submitter, or a grader), you need to change it at a single location. DRY.

You can modify the above approach to show error messages, and do other similar stuff. In case you are looking for more granular authorization control, you can look into cancan gem:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Comment: The issue is an user is at once a submitter and a grader for others. Thus I don't think this solution works. (My apology for unclear question leading you to type up all this...)

Comment: But a user logs in, right? And you probably save the user id in submitter_id and grader_id?

Comment: @Heisenberg - That's not really an issue - you can handle that with associations. For example, you can have a `UserPosts` model that represents the relationship between users and posts (e.g. which user submitted which post). Then you can check whether the post belongs to the user before authorizing them for the edit and grade actions.

Comment: @Heisenberg I have edited the answer. Take a look if that's the use case you are describing.

Comment: Hmm I see -- the `UserPosts` model may be what I need. Could you explain what's going on in the controller though? What method do those codes belong in and what purpose do they serve?

Comment: It's the update method for your resource, or wherever you are trying to save the updates from the view, i.e. the submit action of your form.

Answer (score 0):

Your post model should only be concerned with persisting data.  Better to use plain old ruby objects to encapsulate the higher order behavior of grading and submitting.  Consider using service objects or form objects.

Each service or form object can then include ActiveModel::Model(rails > v4) to get its own validations.

See more about service and form objects here: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

If you only have one submit action and one grade action, its probably ok to keep in one controller. But if you start having multiple actions that are related to submitted, and multiple actions that are related to grading, this sounds like they would make great resources controllers on their own.